# Bounding the order of tournaments without transitive subtournaments of certain size.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, probabilistic-method

> A tournament of order $N$ is a directed graph on $[N]$ obtained by assigning a direction to each edge of $K_{N}$. A tournament $D$ is transitive if for every triple $a, b, c \in N$, $(a, b),(b, c) \in E(D)$ implies that $(a, c) \in E(D)$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $f(n)$ be the maximum integer such that there exists a tournament of order $f(n)$ without a transitive sub-tournament of size $n$. Show that $f(n) > (1+o(1))2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$.

The following is my attempt :

> Claim 2: $f(n) > (1 + o(1))2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$
>
> Proof: Consider the directed graphs on the vertex set $[n]$. A permutation $\sigma$ of $[n]$ gives an unique sequence $\sigma(1) \to \sigma(2) \to \dots \to \sigma(n)$, which corresponds to a directed Hamiltonian path on $K_n$. Hence, by claim 1 (proof omitted), there exists $n!$ transitive tournaments on the underlying graph $K_n$.
>
> Let $T$ be a random tournament on $[N]$, with $N > n$. Let $X$ be the random variable counting the number of transitive tournaments of size $n$ in $T$. By linearity of expectation and the analysis above, we have:
> $$\mathbb{E}[X] = n! {N \choose n} 2^{- {n \choose 2}}$$
> To show the inequality in the claim, we want to find $N$ such that $\mathbb{E}[X] < 1$. Thus we have the following approximation:
> \begin{align*}
> &\ n! {N \choose n} 2^{- {n \choose 2}} = \frac{N!}{(N - n)!2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}} = \left( (1 + o(1))\frac{N}{2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}  \right)^n < 1 \\
> &\Rightarrow (1 +o(1))\frac{N}{2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}} < 1 \\
> &\Rightarrow N < (1 + o(1))2^\frac{n-1}{2} \\
> \end{align*}

I thought I would get something like $N > (1 + o(1))2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$, and since $f(n)$ is the maximum of those $N$’s with the required property, I’d get $f(n) > N > (1 + o(1))2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$.  Where did I go wrong with my arguments?

---

At first I thought that if $N < (1 + o(1))2^\frac{n-1}{2}$ $(\ast)$, then this implies there exists a tournament of order $N$ without a transitive subtournament of order $n$, and so $f(n) > (1 + o(1))2^\frac{n-1}{2}$. But then, say we make the RHS of $(\ast)$ very large, then the inequality still holds, but surely $f(n)$ can’t be arbitrarily large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is nearly correct. By rearranging the last part, the work shows that if $N\le g(n):=(1-o(1))2^{(n-1)/2}$, then there exists a tournament on $N$ vertices lacking copies of the transitive tournament of order  $n$. Hence $f(n)\ge g(n)$ and the desired result follows.

Concretely I think you went wrong when writing out your implication arrows about the size of $N$, which confused the order of quantifiers.

Edit: The correct way to order the last part of your argument is as follows. Let $g(n)$ be the largest $N$ such that $\Bbb{E}[X]=n!\binom{N}{n}2^{-\binom{n}{2}} < 1$. Clearly $f(n)\ge g(n)$. By essentially the same asymptotic analysis as what you gave (since the approximation is sharp), we see that $g(n) \ge (1-o(1))2^{(n-1)/2}$. Hence, we have have that $f(n)\ge g(n) \ge (1-o(1))2^{(n-1)/2}$.

But you instead proved an upper bound for $g(n)$. Namely, your current analysis shows that if $\Bbb{E}[X]<1$ then it is *necessary* for $N$ to be smaller than the RHS. Thus increasing the RHS does lead to a better lower bound for $f(n)$, but rather a weaker upper bound of $g(n)$.

Comment: At first I also thought along the line of $N \leq g(n)$ implying the thing you said (you can see the edit to the post that I made). But then, say we make $g(n)$ very very large, the inequality will still hold but surely $f(n)$ can’t be always greater than $g(n)$?

Comment: this why I said the order you present the implications was wrong. in particular, I will elaborate with an edit.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance but your argument still went over my head. First, I think there’s a typo in the last paragraph (we should have $\mathbb{E}[X] < 1$ instead of $\mathbb{E}[X] > 1$)?

Comment: Secondly, I don’t see how “the same asymptotic analysis” would lead to $g(n) \geq (1-o(1))2^{(n-1)/2}$. And there are actually two issues here: 1. I re-read the three “$<$” in my proof and can’t see how the signs there could be wrong. 2. Shouldn’t we always have $g(n)<(1-o(1))2^{(n-1)/2}$ instead of “$\geq$”? Any $N$ that is larger than $1-o(1))2^{(n-1)/2}$ would lead to $\mathbb{E}[X] \geq 1$, and then we would not be able to conclude that there definitely exists a tournament with $X < 1$. If it’s not too much to ask, could you copy part of my proof and modify it so that it’s clearer? Thanks.

Comment: You were correct about the typo. The same asymptotic analysis applies because the approximation is sharp in both directions. It’s like saying saying $x-o(1) <x<x+o(1)$.

Comment: Regarding your second point, yes what you proved is an upper bound for $g(n)$ (namely that it is at at most $(1+o(1))2^{-(n-1)/2}$). But an upper bound isn’t useful, (the same upper bound would hold for the constant function zero, which wouldn’t give a good bound). Instead you need a lower bound for $g$.

Comment: It seems to me you’re saying that, from $N < (1 + o(1))2^\frac{n-1}{2}$, I can also conclude that $N \geq (1 + o(1))2^\frac{n-1}{2}$?

Comment: this is true but that wasn’t the main point. could you try proving a lower bound for $g$ now? I feel like I’ve given enough advice and hints to help you. if you give this a shot and have further difficulties, please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134347/discussion-between-josh-ng-and-zach-hunter).